# Python 3.6 ftplib STOR error

Tags: python-3.x, ftplib

I have question regarding Python (3.6) and ftplib.
I have reinstalled Windows (10), and one of my old scripts is not working. Problematic line is:

> conn.storlines('STOR runes.txt', open('D:\runes.txt','r'))

Error I keep getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ch1zra\Saved Games\Diablo II\linereader.py", line 108, in <module>
    conn.storlines('STOR runes.txt', open('D:\\runes.txt','r'))
  File "C:\Python\lib\ftplib.py", line 536, in storlines
    if buf[-1] in B_CRLF: buf = buf[:-1]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The file exists.
This worked before, but I was running old version of Python (2.7 IIRC).

Help is highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeError exception says a byte like object is required. Open the file with binary mode.

Change

```
conn.storlines('STOR runes.txt', open('D:\\runes.txt','r'))
```

To:

```
conn.storlines('STOR runes.txt', open('D:\\runes.txt','rb'))
```

Comment: It actualy worked, but shouldn't txt files be opened with 'r' mode?
Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, it should. It is still readable, just converted it to a binary. From the doc page
`Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append 'b' to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability. (Appending 'b' is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and text files differently, where it serves as documentation.)`